# Left joins causing the application to timeout

Tags: sql, join, triggers

I have a trigger that times-out, whenever its triggered however if I comment out one element, it does-not timeout and if i change one left join to just  join, it doesn't timeout but my worry is with just the join i wont be getting all the data including the.

```
UPDATE BH_ASSAY_RESULTS              
   SET                
   PT = LAP_PT.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_VALUE,
        PD = LAP_PD.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_VALUE,
        AU = LAP_AU.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_VALUE,
        RH = LAP_RH.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_VALUE,
        Os = LAP_OS.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_VALUE,
        Ru = LAP_RU.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_VALUE,
        Ir = LAP_IR.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_VALUE,
        LAB_MASS_RECEIVED = LAP_WTREC.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_VALUE 
FROM BH_ASSAY_RESULTS VPGE
JOIN BH_SAMP BHS ON VPGE.PPK = BHS.PK
JOIN LAB_ETL_SAMPLING LET ON BHS.ID = LET.CLIENT_SAMP_ID       
JOIN LAB_SUBMISSION LS ON LS.PK = LET.PPK      
JOIN LAB_BATCH LB ON LB.PK = LS.PPK      
JOIN LAB_ETL LE ON LE.PK = LB.PPK      
JOIN LAB_REP LR ON LET.PK = LR.PPK and LR.REP_ID >= 1
JOIN V_LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY LAP_Pt ON LR.PK = LAP_Pt.LAB_METHOD_PPK and LAP_Pt.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_ID = 'pt' 
JOIN V_LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY LAP_Pd ON LR.PK = LAP_Pd.LAB_METHOD_PPK and LAP_Pd.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_ID = 'Pd' 
LEFT JOIN V_LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY LAP_Au ON LR.PK = LAP_Au.LAB_METHOD_PPK and LAP_Au.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_ID = 'Au'
LEFT JOIN V_LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY LAP_Rh ON LR.PK = LAP_Rh.LAB_METHOD_PPK and LAP_Rh.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_ID = 'Rh' 
LEFT JOIN V_LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY LAP_OS ON LR.PK = LAP_OS.LAB_METHOD_PPK and LAP_OS.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_ID = 'Os' 
LEFT JOIN V_LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY LAP_Ru ON LR.PK = LAP_Ru.LAB_METHOD_PPK and LAP_Ru.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_ID = 'Ru' 
LEFT JOIN V_LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY LAP_IR ON LR.PK = LAP_IR.LAB_METHOD_PPK and LAP_IR.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_ID = 'Ir'
LEFT JOIN V_LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY LAP_WTREC ON LR.PK = LAP_WTREC.LAB_METHOD_PPK and LAP_WTREC.LAB_ASSAY_PRIMARY_RESULT_ID = 'WTREC' 
WHERE LS.PK = @Submission_Pk  and VPGE.LAB_USED = LE.ID  and VPGE.REP_TYPE = LR.REP_ID --LE.ID
```

Comment: What `join` and what line are you referring to in the OP, exactly?

Comment: I got it right by adding another where condition..